# Get requests not working with a certain versions of Angular2 app (node js backend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm working with express and angular 2. When I first began, I forked the Angular2 'get started' project and started working with that, all was fine. But not I decided to create an Angular app properly using angular cli (ng new myapp). And now all my get requests are not working for some reason. I might have a flaw with the logic (how I connect express with angular) 
Here is the github repo with both versions of the angular app. "client1" being the old one and "client" being the new one.

https://github.com/AliObaji/ClearReview-REMASTERED

Here is the current back end code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var CourseColl = require("./models/course");
var profColl = require("./models/professor");

var app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Elissa");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Connection to Elissa established.");
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist")));


app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    console.log("hi");
});

app.get("/courseList", function (req, res) {


    CourseColl.find(function(err,courses){

       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
       else{
           res.json({
               courses: courses
           });
       }
    });


});



app.get("/profList",function (req, res) {

    profColl.find(function(err,profs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json({
                professors: profs
            });
        }
    });
});


app.get('/courseDetails',function (req, res) {

    CourseColl.findById(req.query.id,function(err,myDoc){
       if (err){
           console.log(err);
       }
       else{
           res.json(myDoc);
       }
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

And here is how I'm doing the get requests in angular.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {course} from '../objects/course';

import 'rxjs/Rx'


import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


export class c{
  courses
}



@Injectable()
export class CourseListProvider{

  private courses: Array<course>;

  constructor(private http:Http){

  }
  private c:c;
  getCourses():Observable<c>{
     this.c.courses = this.http.get('/courseList')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
     console.log(c);

    return this.c.courses;
  }
  test(){
    console.log("we have reached here");
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/test/');
  }

  private extractData(res:Response){
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
  }
  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); 
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Please help me with the get requests and any flaws in my logic.
Thank you

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you see any error message?

Comment: No, I just don't see any of the console.log messages that im calling on the server side app.get functions. (for example test() ). I tried using app.use right before any of the app.get functions and I was able to log (through app.use)..

Comment: also if you open the URL in your browser or just with the Angular app?

Comment: Okay i just entered 'localhost:3000/test' into the browser and it worked. So I'm guessing the problem is with how I'm calling it in my Angular service

Comment: It won't actually make a request unless you *subscribe* to the `http.get`.

Comment: For your test() method in the provider: You'll need to return the observable i.e. `this.http.get(...)` in the method.

Comment: Alright guys, thank you so much it worked. Here's what I did.
test(){
    console.log("we have reached here");
    this.http.get('/courseList')
      .subscribe(result => console.log(result.json()))
  }